# Is it possible to split a varialbe period pandas timeseries data object without itteration?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I need to split this cyclical data that has a variable period. I need to detect each sharp rise to split each into its own series, then overlay all they cycles on top of each other for statistical analysis. I was going to do this by just iterating across a python array (and may still), but wanted to give pandas a shot. Seems like this would be a fairly standard operation on cyclical data (not sure about the dynamic period though).

Smart people on stack overflow say not to iterate across a pandas object in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/41022840).
Is it any worse than iterating across a standard python array.
Any tools or vocabulary that I should know to point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is called [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) and is not trivial.

Pandas aside, [dtw-python](https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/python/) is a place to start.